# How to use icon strings with full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to use some custom jpgs for the next and prev button icons.  The docs say to use icon strings but I am not familiar with these, a google search left me just as baffled.  Can anyone explain to me what I need to do to get my jpgs to display on the next and prev buttons of the calendar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [doc](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/buttonIcons/), 
ButtonIcons are based on classes from fullCalendar.css.

> These icon string are transformed into classNames which are styled by
>   FullCalendar's CSS.

So if you want to add your own jpgs, you should create first the .css class, and then modify the buttonIcons object:

```
{
    prev: 'your-prev-class',
    next: 'your-next-class'
}
```